# Minimum requirements to compile a PHP extension

Tags: php, compilation, php-extension

I have the source for a PHP extension, and the compiled version for PHP 5.3. But I have PHP 5.4, and the project appears to have been abandoned.

So given the source code, what is the minimum I have to do to compile it for PHP 5.4?

**EDIT Note**: I'm on Windows.

Comment: http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/09/14/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/ this looks right, with no overkill

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on Windows. That's kind of important, and I left it out - sorry!

Comment: Something like http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the extension itself. If the extension requires some other libraries, like, say the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) extension, then you also need the mysql client library - the C API. Why? Because you explicitly stated that you want minimal dependency requirements. If the extension does not require any other libraries, you can nicely open those C files that you already have, and compile it using any available C compiler. Naturally, you will need PHP development kit as well. :)